# Can we estimate Max and Min of the $\frac 12 . P (B\mid A). P (C\mid A\;\text{and}\; B)$ for $3$ independent events $P(A)=P(B)=P(C)=\frac 12$?

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, optimization, conditional-probability

I have three **dependent** events $A,B,C$, each one happens with probability $\frac 12$. I want to estimate the following probability
$$   P_{tot}=P (A\;\text{and}\; B\;\text{and}\; C)=P (A) \cdot P (\;B\;|\;A\;) \cdot P (\;C\;|\;A\;\text{and}\; B\;)   \\
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad=\frac 12 \cdot P (\;B\;|\;A\;) \cdot P (\;C\;|\;A\;\text{and}\; B\;)  $$

> If I do not have any other information, can we estimate the minimum and maximum value that $P_{tot}$ might have? Does the ordering of the events affect the probability?

Comment: Didn't you post the same exact question before? [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4138841/can-we-estimate-the-minimum-and-maximum-value-of-the-probability-of-union-of-thr#4138841]

Comment: No, my bad. They are almost exact :)

Comment: If you don't have any other information, all you can bound $P(A \cap B \cap C)$ between is $0$ and $1/2$.

Comment: Adding to @VarunVejalla's answer, no, the ordering of the events does not affect the probability.

Comment: @user6247850 There is no max and min like my previous question in this case?